# How to toggle dropdown navigation menu?

Tags: javascript, dropdown

something is wrong with my code, here is what it should do, but doesn't.^^

E.g. on click on "nav 1", slide down and fadein subnavigation, than on click on "nav 2", fade sub navigation 1 out and fade sub navigation 2 in.

This is what I have so fare:

```
var nav = $('.nav li.mega');
nav.children('.subnav-container').slideUp(0);
nav.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    nav.children('.subnav-container').slideUp(500);
    $(this).children('.subnav-container').slideDown(500);
});
```

My fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/rzf7w69u/78/

I hope you guys can help me with my code.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems in the shared code.

1. you are binding event in common class (shared by other elements too).
2. Logic to manage slide up and slide down.
   Here is your code, hope this will help you. 'Happy coding..'

Note: I did the code in your format, so this code can be improve more.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".nav li.mega").hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass("hover");
    $(this).children(".subnav-container").addClass("hover");
},function(){
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
    $(this).children(".subnav-container").removeClass("hover");
});

var nav = $('.nav li.mega');
nav.children('.sibling').slideUp(0);
nav.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var ele=this;
    
    if( $(ele).children('.sibling').hasClass('open')){
      $(ele).children('.sibling').removeClass('open').slideUp(500);
    }
    else
    {
     if(nav.children('.open').length)
        {
        var child=nav.children('.open');
        $(child).removeClass('open').fadeOut(500,function(){         $(ele).children('.sibling').addClass('open').fadeIn(500); });
        }
        else
        {
        $(ele).children('.sibling').addClass('open').slideDown(500);
       }
   }
});
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-top mod_navigation " itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
        <div class="ws-navbar-collapse pull-left">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="submenu mega ncol-3 sibling nav-item dropdown subnav">
                    <a class="" href="url" >
                        <span itemprop="name">Nav 1</span>
                    </a>

                    <div class="subnav-container submenu mega ncol_4 sibling nav-item dropdown">
                        <div class="relative">
                            <ul class="nav sub-nav level-2">
                                <li class="submenu first subnav">
                                    <a class=" " href="url" >
                                        <span itemprop="name">Sub nav 1.1</span>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="subnav-container submenu break_4 last">
                                        <div class="relative">
                                            <ul class="nav sub-nav level-3">
                                                <li class="first">
                                                    <a class=" " href="url" >
                                                        <span itemprop="name">Sub Sub Nav</span>
                                                        <span class="page-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</span>        </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="">
                                                    <a class=" " >
                                                        <span itemprop="name">Sub Sub Nav</span>
                                                        <span class="page-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</span>        </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="">
                                                    <a class=" " >
                                                        <span itemprop="name">Sub Sub Nav</span>
                                                        <span class="page-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</span>        </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="">
                                                    <a class=" ">
                                                        <span itemprop="name">Sub Sub Nav</span>
                                                        <span class="page-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</span>        </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <div class="clear"></div>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="submenu first subnav">
                                    <a class=" " href="url" >
                                        <span itemprop="name">Sub nav 1.2</span>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="subnav-container submenu break_4 last">
                                        <div class="relative">
                                            <ul class="nav sub-nav level-3">
                                                <li class="first">
                                                    <a class=" " href="url" >
                                                        <span itemprop="name">Sub Sub Nav</span>
                                                        <span class="page-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</span>        </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="">
                                                    <a class=" " >
                                                        <span itemprop="name">Sub Sub Nav</span>
                                                        <span class="page-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</span>        </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="">
                                                    <a class=" " >
                                                        <span itemprop="name">Sub Sub Nav</span>
                                                        <span class="page-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</span>        </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="">
                                                    <a class=" ">
                                                        <span itemprop="name">Sub Sub Nav</span>
                                                        <span class="page-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</span>        </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <div class="clear"></div>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="submenu first subnav">
                                    <a class=" " href="url" >
                                        <span itemprop="name">Sub nav 1.3</span>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="subnav-container submenu break_4 last">
                                        <div class="relative">
                                            <ul class="nav sub-nav level-3">
                                                <li class="first">
                                                    <a class=" " href="url" >
                                                        <span itemprop="name">Sub Sub Nav</span>
                                                        <span class="page-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</span>        </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="">
                                                    <a class=" " >
                                                        <span itemprop="name">Sub Sub Nav</span>
                                                        <span class="page-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</span>        </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="">
                                                    <a class=" " >
                                                        <span itemprop="name">Sub Sub Nav</span>
                                                        <span class="page-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</span>        </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="">
                                                    <a class=" ">
                                                        <span itemprop="name">Sub Sub Nav</span>
                                                        <span class="page-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</span>        </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <div class="clear"></div>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="submenu mega ncol-3 sibling nav-item dropdown subnav">
                    <a class="" href="url" >
                        <span itemprop="name">Nav 2</span>
                    </a>

                    <div class="subnav-container submenu mega ncol_4 sibling nav-item dropdown">
                        <div class="relative">
                            <ul class="nav sub-nav level-2">
                                <li class="submenu first subnav">
                                    <a class=" " href="url" >
                                        <span itemprop="name">Sub nav 2.1</span>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="subnav-container submenu break_4 last">
                                        <div class="relative">
                                            <ul class="nav sub-nav level-3">
                                                <li class="first">
                                                    <a class=" " href="url" >
                                                        <span itemprop="name">Sub Sub Nav</span>
                                                        <span class="page-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</span>        </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="">
                                                    <a class=" " >
                                                        <span itemprop="name">Sub Sub Nav</span>
                                                        <span class="page-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</span>        </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="">
                                                    <a class=" " >
                                                        <span itemprop="name">Sub Sub Nav</span>
                                                        <span class="page-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</span>        </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="">
                                                    <a class=" ">
                                                        <span itemprop="name">Sub Sub Nav</span>
                                                        <span class="page-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</span>        </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <div class="clear"></div>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="submenu first subnav">
                                    <a class=" " href="url" >
                                        <span itemprop="name">Sub nav 2.2</span>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="subnav-container submenu break_4 last">
                                        <div class="relative">
                                            <ul class="nav sub-nav level-3">
                                                <li class="first">
                                                    <a class=" " href="url" >
                                                        <span itemprop="name">Sub Sub Nav</span>
                                                        <span class="page-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</span>        </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="">
                                                    <a class=" " >
                                                        <span itemprop="name">Sub Sub Nav</span>
                                                        <span class="page-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</span>        </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="">
                                                    <a class=" " >
                                                        <span itemprop="name">Sub Sub Nav</span>
                                                        <span class="page-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</span>        </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="">
                                                    <a class=" ">
                                                        <span itemprop="name">Sub Sub Nav</span>
                                                        <span class="page-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</span>        </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <div class="clear"></div>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="submenu first subnav">
                                    <a class=" " href="url" >
                                        <span itemprop="name">Sub nav 2.3</span>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="subnav-container submenu break_4 last">
                                        <div class="relative">
                                            <ul class="nav sub-nav level-3">
                                                <li class="first">
                                                    <a class=" " href="url" >
                                                        <span itemprop="name">Sub Sub Nav</span>
                                                        <span class="page-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</span>        </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="">
                                                    <a class=" " >
                                                        <span itemprop="name">Sub Sub Nav</span>
                                                        <span class="page-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</span>        </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="">
                                                    <a class=" " >
                                                        <span itemprop="name">Sub Sub Nav</span>
                                                        <span class="page-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</span>        </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="">
                                                    <a class=" ">
                                                        <span itemprop="name">Sub Sub Nav</span>
                                                        <span class="page-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</span>        </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <div class="clear"></div>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="submenu mega ncol-3 sibling nav-item dropdown subnav">
                    <a class="" href="url" >
                        <span itemprop="name">Nav 3</span>
                    </a>

                    <div class="subnav-container submenu mega ncol_4 sibling nav-item dropdown">
                        <div class="relative">
                            <ul class="nav sub-nav level-2">
                                <li class="submenu first subnav">
                                    <a class=" " href="url" >
                                        <span itemprop="name">Sub nav 3.1</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="submenu first subnav">
                                    <a class=" " href="url" >
                                        <span itemprop="name">Sub nav 3.2</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="submenu first subnav">
                                    <a class=" " href="url" >
                                        <span itemprop="name">Sub nav 3.3</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great, but what I can see, almost before the siv is fully slided up, the subnavigation disapears.

Comment: there is no delay, if you run without CSS, you will see the difference clearly. Removed a unused function so you can check updated one.

Comment: What I see, when its almost slided down it suddenly jumps down and when its almost up, it suddenly jumps up.

Comment: @LydiaMaier I think you did not run the code without CSS, as I mentioned earlier. Now I removed the CSS and you can see there is no sudden jump effects in the animation. So you need to do some updates in CSS, to fix the issue.

Comment: Oh, I'm really really sorry, I didn't know that you mean all the CSS.^^ One last question, is it possible if on click on a nav point with a subnavigation e.g."nav 2", sub navigation 1 fades out and sub navigation 2 fades in and the div "subnav-container" doesn't slide up and down again? Just like here: https://www.invisionapp.com/

Comment: Yes, Update code lines: var child=nav.children('.open');
         $(child).removeClass('open').fadeOut(500,function(){
             $(ele).children('.sibling').addClass('open').fadeIn(500);
            });

Comment: Is it possible to fadein / out the .relative li elements and not the .subnav-container div?

Comment: @LydiaMaier, Thanks for posting question, but looks like you should post your question to any Freelancer development website e.g. www.freelancer.com , there someone surely do the complete code, you want.